# Why Tooltwist Controller deletes or overwrite files in destination server?

Tags: tooltwist

When I use the ToolTwist Controller to deploy my application, it deletes or overwrites files configuration files on the destination server that I don't want changed. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to prevent this. You just need to protect those files or folders that you don't want to be overwritten. To do this, you just need to update the **protect** property of **.fip-destination** file found inside **~/server/** folder.

This is the default value:

```
protect=mysql/.*,tomcat/work/.*,tomcat/logs/.*,protected/.*,tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
```

Sample customized value:

```
protect=mysql/.*,tomcat/work/.*,tomcat/logs/.*,tomcat/lib/.*,tomcat/endorsed/.*,tomcat/bin/.*,tomcat/conf/.*,tomcat/webapps/elbhc.*,tomcat/webapps/ttsvr/WEB-INF/.*,protected/.*
```